# Why does my MySQL query not return full string when I alter the query slightly?

Tags: mysql, missing-data, truncation

I basically have 2 queries that return all the data correctly (zipcodes show 5 digits)

```
select county_name,zipcode,latitude,longitude,city,state from zip_codes limit 4;

select zipcode,latitude,longitude,city,state from zip_codes limit 4
```

and 1 query that leaves off characters for the "zipcode" column in following query:

```
 select zipcode,latitude,longitude,city,state,county_name from zip_codes limit 4;
```

Notice how I changed the locations of "county_name" field.  Is there a reason why MySQL 5.7 Command line Client might be doing this or is it a bug?  If I do same 3 queries in MySQL workbench, all the data is shown correctly.

!"C:\Users\Ryan Donovan\Desktop\Mom Database\weird_query.png"

I have test in Workbench and all queries work fine.  I have tested using ADODB in Excel and result sets returned correct data.  I have restarted command line for MySQL multiple times and get the same thing.

I expect the zipcode field to return 5 characters all the time.

Comment: what does `SHOW CREATE TABLE zip_codes` show?

Comment: zip_codes | CREATE TABLE `zip_codes` (  
    zipcode` char(5) NOT NULL,  
    latitude` decimal(8,4) NOT NULL,  
    longitude` decimal(8,4) NOT NULL,  
    city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,  
    state` char(2) NOT NULL,  
    county_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,  
    PRIMARY KEY (`zipcode`),  
    KEY `state` (`state`),  
    CONSTRAINT `zip_codes_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`zipcode`) 
   REFERENCES `zip_info` (`zipcode`),  
    CONSTRAINT `zip_codes_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`state`) REFERENCES  `states` (`state`)  
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |